# How to add widgets to toolbar and increase its height

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am looking to add a couple of EditTexts to the toolbar in my activity as well as increase its height according to the Material design specs something like the image below :

[image]

How do I achieve this i.e. how do I add normal widgets to the toolbar and increase it height ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't believe but its so simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"            // Height of toolbar 
android:background="@color/anycolor">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=""/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=""/>   

//Add as many widgets as you want

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: You're right. I never expected it to be this easy !